# AWS SNS > SQS > Lambda Trigger. Is this async or sync invocation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am using
**Client > SNS > SQS > Lambda Trigger**

As per my understanding, **SNS > Lamda** will be an asynchronous invocation

However, **SNS > SQS > Lambda** supposed to be synchronous.

1. Is my understanding correct?

I have configured DLQ on the SQS source but doesn’t store failed message into DLQ. Also saw 2x retried attempt on Lambda cloudwatch.

2. If **SNS > SQS > Lambda** is synchronous, I think this should not happen am I right?

Comment: Yep, sqs to lambda is sync.

Comment: Thanks It is clear! So on lambda trigger failure, the message should be retained in sqs queue. I think referrerring to the 2nd question above, it does not retain because probably the lambda return 200 to SQS but within lambda itself got failure calling an API (async http call). Therefore, lamda perform 2x retries and discard the event.  I will test my hypotesis and share result once i got chance.

Answer (score 4):

@jellycsc already answered your question in the comment section, but i would like to expand it. Shortly it is poll based which uses `synchronous` invocation for it.

There are three type of invocation models for AWS Lambda

1. Synchronous

   - Elastic Load Balancing
   - Alexa
   - Cognito
   - API Gateway (there is an async version of it too)
2. Asynchronous

   - S3
   - SNS
   - Cloudwatch/Eventbridge events
3. Poll-based

   - Kinesis
   - SQS
   - DynamoDB streams

According to the this [blogpost](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/understanding-the-different-ways-to-invoke-lambda-functions/)

> AWS will manage the poller on your behalf and perform `Synchronous` invokes of your function with this type of integration. The retry behavior for this model is based on data expiration in the data source. For example, Kinesis Data streams store records for 24 hours by default (up to 168 hours).

Comment: Thanks It is clear! So on lambda trigger failure, the message should be retained in sqs queue. I think referrerring to the 2nd question above, it does not retain because probably the lambda return 200 to SQS but within lambda itself got failure calling an API (async http call). Therefore, lamda perform 2x retries and discard the event.  I will test my hypotesis and share result once i got chance.

Comment: with SQS + DLQ integrated and when it exceeds the attempt it should be on DLQ even there is an application layer error(exception etc). `When your function returns an error, Lambda leaves it in the queue. After the visibility timeout occurs, Lambda receives the message again. To send messages to a second queue after a number of receives, configure a dead-letter queue on your source queue.` looking forward to hear from your tests @AdrianusHendry . Best.